# How to link a Discord Voice Channel in Chat? [Discord GUI]

Tags: discord

How do you link a voice channel in a text channel using the GUI? I know you can link another text channel by using `#<channel name>` where <channel name> is the channel you want to link but how would you do so for a voice channel?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only way to do this is to first enable developer mode on discord [User Settings > Appearance > Advanced: Developer Mode: Enable]

Then to link a voice channel, right click on the voice channel to link, click "Copy ID" [see below], then in the text chat type `<#IDHERE>` where IDHERE must be replaced with the ID you just copied to the clipboard (ie. `<#386392044337233922>`)

[image]

Now this should update to the voice channel you are linking
[image]

Likewise you can do this for a thread you want to link